# Can you determine what country your user is in from an iOS app?

Tags: ios, location, units-of-measurement

I'm trying to determine whether to use imperial or metric units automatically before asking the user to enable location services. I know that you can't get precise data but all I really need is United States or not. Can you determine what store it was downloaded from or use IP address or anything like that?

Comment: Use one of the built-in formatters for mass / distance / energy etc.. (among many others) to do this. It will automatically format the value / string with the settings the user has chosen. See the `NSFormatter` documentation to pick the appropriate formatter: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSFormatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for NSLocale:

```
    let theLocale = NSLocale.autoupdatingCurrentLocale()
    print(theLocale.objectForKey(NSLocaleMeasurementSystem))
    print(theLocale.objectForKey(NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem))
```

Look at the NSLocale class reference for more options.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the device's locale to achieve this...

**Obj-C**

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
```

**Swift**

```
let locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
let countryCode = locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode)
```

Country codes are in the format US (United States), FR (France), etc...

Note that the locale is based on the user's device settings and not necessarily the current physical location of the device.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

```
NSLocale.current
NSLocale.Key.countryCode
```

Yes, annoyingly renamed again, don't you have more important stuff to attend Swift team???